# Spark - remove rows from windows on dynamic condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my dataframe:

```
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| key1 | key2 | timestamp | status  |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1000      | event_a |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1100      | null    |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1200      | event_b |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1300      | null    |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1200      | event_a |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1300      | event_b |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1400      | null    |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1500      | null    |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
```

I'd like to group rows by `key1` and `key2` (probably using window function?) and then, from each group remove rows older than `event_b` - based on timestamp.

So the result would be:

```
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| key1 | key2 | timestamp | status  |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1000      | event_a |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1100      | null    |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 111  | 1200      | event_b |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1200      | event_a |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
| AAA  | 222  | 1300      | event_b |
+------+------+-----------+---------+
```

There may be more statuses between `event_a` and `event_b`, but always `event_b` will be the last, with nulls after.

I'm aware that removing elements from dataframe is impossible. I mean to create new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Windowing can make this happen. Considering you have read your data into a dataframe `df`, then below logic should result into your desired output.

Hope this helps.

```
 df = (
    df
    .withColumn("check", 
        when(lag('status,1)
           .over(
            Window
            .partitionBy('key1,'key2)
            .orderBy('timestamp)
         )===lit("event_b"),1)
         .otherwise(0)
    )
    .withColumn("finalCheck",
            sum('check)
            .over(Window.partitionBy('key1,'key2)
            .orderBy('timestamp)))
    .filter("finalCheck <= 0")
    .drop('finalCheck)
    .drop('check).show
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a windowing function, and even if you used a window function, you would make two full passes of the data.  One way to do it is just to create a filtered dataFrame with the "event_b" rows and then compare against it and keep the rows you want based on the timestamp.

```
val testDF = Seq(
 ("AAA", 111, 1000, "event_a"),
 ("AAA", 111, 1100, null),
 ("AAA", 111, 1200, "event_b"),
 ("AAA", 111, 1300, null),
 ("AAA", 222, 1200, "event_a"),
 ("AAA", 222, 1300, "event_b"),
 ("AAA", 222, 1400, null),
 ("AAA", 222, 1500, null)                           
).toDF("key1", "key2", "timestamp", "status")


val bDF = testDF.filter("status = 'event_b'")
  .withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "bTimestamp")
  .drop("status")

val joinedF = testDF.join(bDF, Seq("key1", "key2"))
  .withColumn("dropCol", col("bTimestamp") >= col("timestamp"))
  .filter("dropCol")
  .drop("bTimestamp")
  .drop("dropCol")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use self join to get the desired result.

Suppose I have registered this dataframe as table name **data**.I can write a spark sql query like below :-

SELECT t1.*
FROM data t1 join data t2 ON t1.key1=t2.key1 AND t1.key2=t2.key2
WHERE t2.status="event_b" AND t2.timestamp